# HTML Agility Pack can't find classes with trailing spaces

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I use following code to parse an HTML document:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(pageStr);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[@class='the-title']");
```

but it fails to find following string:

```
<h3 class="the-title ">
```

and works only if the trailing space is removed from class.

Can HTML agility pack handle this situation by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using XPath `normalize-space()` to remove unnecessary white-spaces before doing comparison :

```
//h3[normalize-space(@class)='the-title']
```

**working demo example :**

```
var html = @"<div>
    <h3 class='the-title '/>
</div>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h3[normalize-space(@class)='the-title']");
Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
```

<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M0E34r)</kbd>

**output :**

```
<h3 class='the-title '></h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

'the-title' != "the-title "

You can solve your issue by using the 'contains' function within your Xpath query

Try the following:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[contains(@class, 'the-title')]");
```

Comment: what about "the-title1" ? Will it be found too?